# PHP check if first few characters of string are contained in an array

Tags: php, arrays

I am currently using this:

```
if(strtolower(substr($subject,0,3)) != 're:' and strtolower(substr($subject,0,3)) != 'fw:' and strtolower(substr($subject,0,1)) != '#' and strtolower(substr($subject,0,5)) != 'read:') {
```

to check if the first characters of the `$subject` variable are not equal to,

- re:
- fw:
- #
- read:

in uppercase or lowercase, how can i check exactly the same thing but by using items contained in an array instead?

like:

```
$array = array("re:", "fw:", "#", "read:");
```

Comment: items of what?? use `foreach` in php

Comment: fairly obvious but check my update

Comment: You could use `preg_match` with an array for the haystack and a regex like `^re:|^fw:|^#|^read:`

Comment: Did you check out my answer?

Answer (score 2):

```
foreach (array('re:', 'fw:', '#', 'read:') as $keyword) {
    if (stripos($subject, $keyword) === 0) {
        echo 'found!';
        break;
    }
}
```

or

```
$found = array_reduce(array('re:', 'fw:', '#', 'read:'), function ($found, $keyword) use ($subject) {
    return $found || stripos($subject, $keyword) === 0;
});
```

or

```
if (preg_match('/^(re:|fw:|#|read:)/i', $subject)) {
    echo 'found!';
}
```

or

```
$keywords = array('re:', 'fw:', '#', 'read:');
$regex    = sprintf('/^(%s)/i', join('|', array_map('preg_quote', $keywords)));

if (preg_match($regex, $subject)) {
    echo 'found!';
}
```

Comment: on your preg_match option, could i still use strtolower ?

Comment: You don't need to. The `i` handles case insensitivity. Just as the `i` in `stripos`.

Comment: ah i see ok, could i put them in an array? like in my question?

Comment: If you want to, apply `strtolower` to `$subject`. It won't do anything, but you *can* do it.

Comment: i want to put the re: / fw: etc in an array and check the array?

Comment: Ah, well, yes, you could create the regex dynamically of course. See update.

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap the functionality of matching a string against a set of prefixes in a function:

```
function matches_prefixes($string, $prefixes)
{
    foreach ($prefixes as $prefix) {
        if (strncasecmp($string, $prefix, strlen($prefix)) == 0) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

And use like this:

```
if (!matches_prefixes($subject, ['re:', 'fw:', '#', 'read:'])) {
    // do stuff
}
```

See also: [`strncasecmp`](http://php.net/strncasecmp)

Comment: You either want `stripos` or a third parameter for `strncasecmp`.